What is this movie that involved African Tsetse flies?
Many years ago my father showed me a movie about young white-skinned boy in Africa with a pet lion and a black man who gets sick from tsetse flies and is covered in white plaster.
What is the title of this movie that features tsetse flies?

It might be helpful if you suggested a likely range of years you saw this movie as this can eliminate more recent options.

What do you mean 'white plaster' .... dust? solid plater casts? sticking plasters / band-aids? calamine lotion (zinc-oxide which dries to a white/pink finish).

Could this be Duma (2005)?





It's about a boy named Xan (Alexander Michaletos) who befriends a cheetah cub (rather than a lion), after its mother was killed by lions.
As Duma grows up, Xan has to return him to the wild, where they meet a man named Ripkuna, or Rip (Eamonn Walker), who protects Xan from an attack by a swarm of Tsetse flies.
Rip is brought to a village where the local people are able to cure him. The treatment involves placing a clay mask on his face.


From a quick reading, the bites can cause ulcers, which I guess could be treated with a topical medicine like calamine lotion, which dries to a white layer on the skin. But that is not the serious symptoms of sleeping sickness, which is the disease carried by the flies.

Thanks @Valorum, for finding out more about the "covered in white plaster" bit!
